# How to read Serialize form data in target url

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

I'm using the following JQUERY/AJAX to submit a form

```
$('#id-frmNewAsset').submit(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var post_url = "actions/add-it-asset-to-db.asp";
var method = "post";
var form_data = $(this).serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: post_url,
    type: method,
    data: form_data
}).done(function(response){
    alert("success");
});
});
```

I know the post url is being called, but how do I "un" serialize the form data to add it to my database.

Thanks

Comment: It will be sent across as normal post data input on the request.  However you would normally access that stuff by key, it's the same.  Your backend in this case has nothing to unserialize.

Comment: Thanks, Taplar didnt think it was the easy.

Answer (score -1):

This is a POST request, so data is sent just like any normal POST request.
In asp (since you have that in the tags) you use the following:

```
Request.Form["field_name"]
```